# how to generate a unique key for 2d array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i need to generate a unique key for a two dimensional  array 
but i will have the same numbers every time but in different position in array 
example

first array

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
7 8 6
```

---

second time

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
```

---

and so on

**NOTE** : 
my array will have the values from 0 to 8 every time but in  different position

Comment: i dont need to compare the array i need to find a unique key for each

Comment: I deleted that comment because I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Do you want to get the key for an array, so that the same array produces the same key? Like for comparison, saving \ restoring etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you need to create unique for each number from 0 to 8
So you can do this by using array, list or more dynamically by using Dictionnary

Using Array:

```
string[] numbersUnique = new string[] {"zero","one"....."eight"};
 Console.WriteLine("The unique key of {0} is {1}", 2, numbersUnique [2]);
```

Using Dictionary:

```
   Dictionary<int, string> numbers = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                {
                {0,"zero"},
                {1,"one"},
                {2,"two"},
                {3,"three"},
                // .
                // .
                {8,"eight"}
                };

                Console.WriteLine("The unique key of {0} is {1}", 2, numbers[2]);
```